# CLI Tizen build-web displays Invalid Password error

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to build a tizen web application for a Samsung Active 2 smartwatch from CLI (Arch linux) and I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Main.java(195) - org.tizen.common.sign.exception.CertificationException: Invaild password
```

I've followed this manual: [Tizen CLI manual](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli?langredirect=1)

The command I use to build the package is:

```
tizen package -t wgt -s CertificateName  -- .
```

Where CertificateName is the name of my already existing certificate that I created using also the CLI with the command:

```
tizen certificate -a CertificateName -p password -n Name -e fake@email.com
```

After generating the certificate I've added to the security profiles using the command:

```
tizen security-profiles add -n author -a /home/user/tizen-studio-data/keystore/author/author.p12 -p password
```

And after it, I've added the Trust Anchor to the project with the command:

```
tizen trust-anchor set -c /home/user/tizen-studio-data/keystore/author/author.p12 -s true -- projectfolder
```

How can I fix the Invalid Password error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `tizen package`, the app checks the certificates' entries of the default profile.xml file that you set. It should look like this:

```
<profileitem ca="<tizen>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/developer/tizen-developer-ca.cer" distributor="0" key="<tizen-data>/keystore/author/<cert>.p12" password="<tizen-data>/keystore/author/<cert>.pwd" rootca=""/>

<profileitem ca="<tizen>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-ca.cer" distributor="1" key="<tizen>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-signer.p12" password="<tizen-data>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-signer.pwd" rootca=""/>
```

Actually, the passwords aren't stored in the *.pwd files but in the `Login` keyring of `gnome-keyring`. In order to retrieve the passwords previously stored by calling `tizen security-profiles add`, `tizen package` calls:

`<tizen>/tools/certificate-encryptor/secret-tool lookup --label=tizen-studio`.

You'll see by using the command above that you'll have an error giving more information than `tizan package`. In your case, `gnome-keyring` may not be installed or the `Login` keyring may not be correctly initialized.

**SOLUTION #1**

To resolve the issue the simplest thing to do is to install/reinstall the `gnome-keyring` package and reboot (or restart gnome-keyring-daemon):

```
pacman -S gnome-keyring
reboot
```

This should add the `Login` keyring and if it doesn't you can add it manually using `seahorse` or `echo <PASSWORD> | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock`

Finally, re-add your profile with `tizen security-profiles add`. You can see the [Tizen blog post](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/how-manage-certificates-and-package-applications-different-ubuntu-setups?langswitch=en) for remote/docker configuration.

**SOLUTION #2**

If you don't want to bother with gnome-keyring you can try to add the passwords directly in the profiles.xml file as shown on the [Tizen forum](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/pwd-fle-format-profile.xml-certificates?langswitch=en) and written below:

```
<profileitem ca="<tizen>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/developer/tizen-developer-ca.cer" distributor="0" key="<tizen-data>/keystore/author/<cert>.p12" password="<strong_password>" rootca=""/>

<profileitem ca="<tizen>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-ca.cer" distributor="1" key="<tizen>/tools/certificate-generator/certificates/distributor/tizen-distributor-signer.p12" password="tizenpkcs12passfordsigner" rootca=""/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Solution #2 worked for me. However, I tried solution #1 and could not get it working. I am running on a Windows 11 / WSL 2 environment with Ubuntu and Tizen Studio installed on it. This is fairly new kind of thing being able to run Linux GUI apps on Windows. Any advice on what alternate steps I could take somewhere along the lines of solution #1?

Comment: The "secret-tool" suggestion was most helpful to me. It pointed out that the real underlying error was a missing binary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found for this was to create a new certificate, and make sure that the password only contains lowercase letters and numbers

I was previously getting this error when my password contained non-alphanumeric symbols, but am not getting the error with the new password